# Can anyone identify this shrub/berry

Tags: identification, leaves, shrubs, berries

I have a shrub in the garden which has been there for 5 years. Only this year it bloomed very tiny white petal flowers early March and is now producing red berries.

I live in Scotland, Uk[image]

Answer (score 4):

Your shrub looks very much like a Nanking cherry bush. The cherries are small, but when they turn dark red, they are very sweet. The kids (and birds) love them. I've had one in my yard for years, and I've noticed that they spread quite easily.

Comment: Confirmed this with a likelihood of 93% using identify.plantnet.org and the attached photo